# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text could not be parsed at index "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"

Tags: java, date, datetime-parsing, datetimeparseexception

My code is:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
String filterValue = "01.03.2021 0:01";
LocalDateTime parsedDate = LocalDateTime.parse(filterValue, formatter);
```

I get the exception
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '01.03.2021 0:01' could not be parsed at index 11

Comment: try to use this format "01.03.2021 00:01";

Comment: or this pattern: `"dd.MM.yyyy H:mm"`. By the way, index 11 is the `0`, use only one if you are parsing values with single-digit hours of day.

Comment: Indexes in Java are 0-based, so index 11 is `0`, not the space character.

Comment: `0:01` doesn't match `HH:mm`

Answer (score 1):

The format says "HH" but the value provided is "0".
"01.03.2021 00:01"
works.

I think its pretty unpractical to force a leading zero for the hour but well, i got a solution.

Comment: use the pattern suggested by deHaar in the question "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm"

Comment: with `HH` you are explicitly requesting for the leading `0`. use just one `H` if you don't find practical to have a leading `0`.